# Phonegap leaves blank space at the end of the page

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using cordova 1.9.0 and jquery mobile 1.3.2 . I am developing an app in phonegap on android . But at the end of every page i am getting a blank space . the space is not visible initially but when i scroll the header up the blank space is visible . I have tried implementing every solution in stackoverflow, but none worked . How to do this ? 
some of my code goes like this :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Slider Stop</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.9.0.js">    </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>App</h1>
    </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                <li id="listitem">Swipe Right to view Page 1</li>
            </ul>
            </p>
        </div>
             <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Footer content</h4>
    </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us an example of your page? Even create a jsFiddle example, here's a template for jQuery Mobile 1.3.2: http://jsfiddle.net/PMrDn/626/

Comment: Screenshot would be helpful too.